# buscador con resultados de tablas relacionadas php

Tags: php, mysql

Un placer, mi consulta es la siguiente:

Tengo un buscador sencillo y básico que me trae resultados de manera perfecta pero, en mi tabla usuarios tengo datos de otra tabla de los cuales solo guardo el ID de la tabla departamentos en mi tabla usuarios., lo que quiero es: en el resultado de búsqueda no quiero ver el número de ID que tengo guardado desde la tabla departamentos, quiero ver el nombre completo, se que se hace con inner join pero lo he intentado ya varias veces y no me funciona, solo me tira el ID y no el texto.

```html
<?php
   if(!empty($_POST)){
      $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['PalabraClave']);
      $query ="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre1 like '%".$aKeyword[0]."%' ";

      for($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
          if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
              $query .= " OR perfil like '%".$aKeyword[$i]."%'";
          }
      }
      $result = $db->query($query);
      echo "<br>Tu búsqueda fue:<b> ". $_POST['PalabraClave']."</b>";          
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $row_count=0;
      echo "<br><br>Resultados: ";
      echo "<br><table class='table table-striped'>";
         While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
         $row_count++;                         
            echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$row_count." </td>
                  <td>".$row['nombre1']."</td>
                  <td>".$row['id_deptos']."</td>
                  </tr>";
            }
           echo "</table>";
        }else{
             echo "<br>Resultados: Ninguno";
        }
    }
?>
```

Ese es el codigo del resultado de busqueda.

Les paso la imagen de lo que tengo por ahora y que es lo que quiero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he intentando hasta el momento es esto:

```html
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST)){
    $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['PalabraClave']);
    $query ="SELECT Us.id, Us.nombre1, Us.nombre2, Us.apellido1, Us.apellido2, Us.perfil, Dep.deptos FROM usuario Us
    INNER JOIN depto Dep ON Us.id_deptos = Dep.deptos 
    WHERE Us.nombre1 like '%".$aKeyword[0]."%' OR Us.nombre2 like '%".$aKeyword[0]."%' OR Us.apellido1 like '%".$aKeyword[0]."%' OR Us.apellido2 like '%".$aKeyword[0]."%' ";

    for($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
        if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
            $query .= " OR Us.perfil like '%".$aKeyword[$i]."%'";
        }
    }
    $result = $db->query($query);
    echo "<br>Has buscado por:<b> ". $_POST['PalabraClave']."</b>";          
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       $row_count=0;
           echo "<br><br>Resultados encontrados: ";
           echo "<br><table class='table table-striped'>";
                While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
                  $row_count++;                         
                  echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$row_count." </td>
                      <td>".$row['nombre1']." ".$row['nombre2']." ".$row['apellido1']." ".$row['apellido2']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['deptos']."</td>
                     </tr>";
                  }
              echo "</table>";
           }else {
                  echo "<br>Resultados encontrados: Ninguno";
                 }
           }
      ?>
```

Y cuando realizo la busqueda con ese codigo, me sale que no hay resultados en la busqueda, aunque si los hay pero no los presenta...

Las estructuras de mis tablas son estas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es ver el nombre del departamento que esta guardado en la tabla depto, no necesito ver el ID de ese nombre... El ID del nombre depto lo tengo en mi tabla usuarios...

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Agrega la estructura de tus tablas por favor y lo que hayas intentado al momento

Comment: BetaM, buen día... Ya agregué lo que me pedistes... Se que algo estoy haciendo mal pero no encuentro donde... Tengo otras tablas con la misma lógica de relación que presento acá y funcionan, solo el resultado de búsqueda no me funciona.